# Data annotation on int[]

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

In a ASP.NET MVC5, I'm using the chosen JS library for a multi-dropdown select. How Can I do to use Data Annotation to validate the field?

Actually I use `[Required]` on all fields, this multi-dropdown select too, but it isn't working.

Code:

```
[MinLength(1)]
public int[] fields{ get; set; }
```

Here is my Code in the cshtml:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.fields, Model.fieldsSelect, new { data_placeholder = "pholder" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fields, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Without the plugin I currently use (chosen) there is no validation , Here is the HTML rendered without chosen:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
                <select data-placeholder="Enter multiple fields" data-val="true" data-val-minlength="The field fieldsmust be a string or array type with a minimum length of '1'." data-val-minlength-min="1" id="fields" multiple="multiple" name="fields">
<option value="944454">WARUYFJGHIE</option>
<option value="33033095">WEBJKHGJHGVHGAN</option>
</select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="fields" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

            </div>
```

Validation works for all my string but not this one: when I select nothing on the form, all [Required] for strings works: an error message is apparing and submit is not hitting the controller/server, but not the [MinLength(1)]... No error message and when I fill all except [MinLength(1)], the form is submitting and error occurs in the controller/server because of null.

Versions of JS validations:

- jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.11.1 - 3/22/2013
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js : no version (neither in the
  jquery.validate.unobtrusive..js)

Comment: You must have great eye sight :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: thank you. I always have telescope in case of haha! (right click copy url paste do the trick) but in fact I use chosen Jquery library that hide the field that must be validated and the jquery validator don't care of hidden fields so I've tried to position: absolute; left: -9999px; display:block!important; but this isn't working

Comment: OK, now I understand (would have been good to mention that earlier). You can override the validator to not ignore hidden fields (I have posted something about this before so let me try and find it)

Comment: I already tried your first snippet :-) but it wasn't working in my case (or I didn't applied this correctly). Yes, I wasn't thinking that chosen hidden the control, I apologise!

Comment: I have updated answer showing how to include validation on hidden fields, but check the location of the scripts - if the `$.validator` parses the form before the plugin is applied to the element (i.e. before its hidden) there may not be a problem - I don't use `chosen` so not sure

Comment: And BTW, applying a style even with `!important` would not work, because that is parsed as the control is being generated - after that the plugin is added which then overrides your style

Comment: @StephenMuecke: did you finally had some sime to test? Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MinLengthAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[MinLength(1)]
public int[] fields{ get; set; }
```

**Edit**

Based on additional comments, a jquery plugin is being used that hides the `<select>`. By default hidden fields are not validated. To include hidden fields, add the following

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
 ignore: []
});
```

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke but I've did it and it isn't work, no error message on the webpage...

Comment: Then you need to update to MVC 5.1 [Refer release notes here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Unobtrusive)

Comment: Its a Nuget package. [Refer this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/01/20/announcing-the-release-of-asp-net-mvc-5-1-asp-net-web-api-2-1-and-asp-net-web-pages-3-1.aspx)

Comment: Should be working then. Do you have the latest `jquery`, `jquery-validate` and `jquery-validate-unobtrusive` files (if your using 5.2 then you should, but could you copied them from a another project?)

Comment: thanks for your replies. I used the js included in the project, and simple [Request] are working so I think all is OK for js Libraries. i've updated the question to show js libraries.

Comment: You should remove `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>` (you have already included it with `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` - either that or remove the bundle) and use the non minified versions (your cant debug it using the min versions)

Comment: no, jQuery UI isn't in the bundle for the moment. it's in a separate folder. I will put it in bundle wafter but thanks :-)
I can remove it for teste if ou think it can make errors

Comment: thanks. When I put your code in the JS of this page, even if the listbox has 0 selected items, the form submit to the controller, do I forget something? No error in console

Comment: I haven't used `chosen` (my plugin are better :) ) so cant be sure. If you just use the standard select (without the plugin) does it work?

Comment: what is your plugin? :-) I've edited the initial post, same issue than with chosen, no validation!

Comment: Weird (I only have MVC 4 on this laptop so cant test until tomorrow). And its my own plugin - [article here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768069/MVC-Custom-Select-Control) if your interested

Comment: I've edited the first message to be more clear. I double-checked all but all looks great for me.. Thanks for your answer/time :-)

Comment: did you have some time to test ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @clement, Sorry for the delay. When MVC 5.1 came out I tested it and it worked (got a client side error), but I cant seem to reproduce it. Maybe I also had the `[Required]` attribute on the property as well, but cant remember. When I get some time I'll debug the jquery-validate.js file and see exactly what happening.